# Change of variables in path integral

Tags: quantum-mechanics, path-integral, calculus

In this paper https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/perry.6/p5501_sp17/articles/Wikberg_PathIntegrals.pdf the author does a change of variables $\eta = x - x_{0}$ on pg 13. He then writes $dx_{0}$ as $d\eta$. But should it not be $d\eta$ = $-dx_{0}$? Since $\frac{dx_0}{d\eta} = -1$? Why is it +1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a typo. The author wanted to define $\eta:=x_0 -x$, as is evident later on where they substitute $\frac{x+x_0}{2}$ by $x+\frac{\eta}{2}$ and $x_0$ by $x+\eta$.

Answer (score -1):

The author probably also changed the integration limits. While it is true that $d\eta=-d x_0$, one has

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty d\eta=\int_{\infty}^{-\infty}(-dx_0)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx_0.$$

Thus, one could say $d\eta=dx_0$ as long as one remembers to retain the standard order of the integration limits!